# python plot csv keyerror

Tags: python, csv, plot, keyerror

```
    import pandas as pd
    from datetime import datetime
    import csv
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.dates as mdates
    headers = ['Sensor Value','Date','Time']
    df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\aaa\\Desktop\\python_test\\roaddata.CSV',names=headers)
    print (df)




    x = df['Time']
    y = df['Distance']

    # plot
    plt.plot(x,y)

    plt.show()




----------------CSV is below--------------------

Date, Time, Elapsed time, Distance, Speed (km/h), Latitude, Longitude, Accuracy (meters), Altitude, Altitude accuracy
8.01.2018, 18:15:52 GMT+3, 00:00, 0.00, 17.2, 40.973487, 29.232253, 5.000000, 130.674511, 4.000000 
8.01.2018, 18:15:55 GMT+3, 00:02, 0.02, 20.6, 40.973647, 29.232361, 5.000000, 130.701052, 4.000000 
8.01.2018, 18:15:58 GMT+3, 00:05, 0.04, 20.6, 40.973834, 29.232479, 8.333333, 130.091269, 4.000000 
8.01.2018, 18:16:01 GMT+3, 00:08, 0.06, 20.6, 40.973989, 29.232586, 5.000000, 129.352620, 4.000000
```

-------------error----------------

i have error "keyerror", even informations are in csv, i couldnt figure out why,  it gives errors in y defination like Distance, Time etc

please help me, thanks...

KeyError: 'Distance'

Comment: `print df.keys()` if `Distance` is not in the list, then the construction of your dataframe `df` is incorrect.

Comment: thanks Jacob i solved it... additonally i want to graph only specific km/h vs time on entire column how can do it?

--------select column km/h and select which are 100km/h in km/h column and graph vs times at time columns-----